# How can i proof by absurd with coq?

Tags: coq

I am reading Logical Foundations from Software Foundations series and i saw the `plus_id_example` that is:

```
Theorem plus_id_example : forall n m:nat,
  n = m ->
  n + n = m + m.

Proof.
  intros n m.
  intros H.
  rewrite H.
  reflexivity.  Qed.
```

I could understand the solution, so i tried to solve it using absurd, what i want to do is:

Lets consider by absurd, that `n+n <> m+m`, so we have `2n <> 2m`, `n <> m`, which is a contradiction since we have `n=m` as our hypothesis.

How could i write this using Coq tactics?

Comment: If you do not want to use any fancy lemmas/tactics, I do not think that you can avoid some form of rewriting in your proof (at the step where you want to go from `2n <> 2m` to `n = m`), and so you will get a proof at least as complicated as the one of Software Foundation. In general, in this kind of easy examples, reasoning by contradiction is just a way to hide a direct reasoning, so in the end you’ll perform the same steps, just hidden behind negations.

Comment: Hey thanks for the guide, but thats was actually my goal, im a beginner to Coq and discrete math in general, so while i was reading this example i thought "hey, how can i use absurd in this case to prove it" as a way of develop my skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the many contraposition-based lemmas in Coq: you can see them by using, for instance, `Search "contra".` in Coq.

Using the ssreflect tactic language, a proof based on this idea can be obtained as follows (I'm sure there must be shorter proofs):

```
Theorem plus_id_example : forall n m:nat,
  n = m ->
  n + n = m + m.
Proof.
  move=> n m.
  apply: contra_eq.
  have twice : forall p, p + p = p * 2.
    move=> p.
    by rewrite -iter_addn_0 /= addn0.
  by rewrite !twice eqn_mul2r.
Qed.
```

Comment: Is using SSreflex the simplest way? Since im a beginner in Coq i would like to try it using the builtin tactics

Comment: I found SSReflect easier to understand, as a beginner, than the standard Coq tactic language. Of course, this is subjective.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the connection between some propositions and boolean expressions, which is at the core of the reflection mechanism behind SSReflect, allows many contrapositive lemmas such as `contra_eq` to be expressed in a simple manner.